# I edit a selected item and the initial collection is changed automatically changes and continues to add when I click

Tags: javascript, angularjs

**I click on an item in my collection A and charge to collection B, the problem is that: when any modification in the Value of Collection B also changes the item of collection A.
How can I solve that detail.**

the sum is exceeded by several clicks

```js
  var app = angular.module("RodoApp", []);

  app.controller("RodoController", function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.data_List = [{Value: 100 },
                        {Value: 200},
                        {Value: 300},];
    $scope.List_Add = [];
    $scope.click_Add = function (data) {
      if ($scope.List_Add.indexOf(data) == -1) {
        $scope.List_Add.push(data);
    $scope.Sum = () => $scope.List_Add.reduce((Value, b) => { return Value + b.Value; }, 0);  //Here SUM

      }
    }

    $scope.click_Update = function (data, newValue) {
      data.Value = newValue;
    }
  });
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="RodoApp" ng-controller="RodoController">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data_List">
      <td ng-click="click_Add(data)">{{ data.Value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in List_Add">
      <td>
        <a href="#" ng-show="!show_Update" ng-click="model_Value = data.Value; show_Update = true">{{ data.Value }}</a>
        <div ng-show="show_Update">
          <input type="text" ng-model="model_Value">
          <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="click_Update(data, model_Value); show_Update = false;">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
<tr>
  <td>Sum: {{Sum()}}</td>
</tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

more details. [CodePen](https://codepen.io/roalroga/pen/BaBjwLR?editors=1000)

when I make several clicks to a collection item B the sum does not stop.

[image]

Comment: this is a common problem. the issue is that when you copy from a to b, you're actually just copying a reference from b and not the values. i'm not exactly sure how to get around this problem, but you should start with cloning the properties from `data` and seeing if the problem persists. another solution maybe to `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(data))` then add the result to `b` and see if it works

Comment: @r3wt What do you think of the answer below?

Comment: try it and see if it works. both examples are cloning the object so in theory they should no longer be a shared reference. in practice sometimes it doesn't work and additional steps are required.

Answer (score 3):

When you push `data` to `List_Add`, items in both the arrays are referencing the same object. So, you could clone the data using [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) or [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Polyfill) before pushing to `List_Add`

```
$scope.List_Add.push({ ...data })
```

or

```
$scope.List_Add.push(Object.assign({}, data))
```

Updated snippet:

```js
var app = angular.module("RodoApp", []);

app.controller("RodoController", function($scope, $http) {
  $scope.data_List = [{Value: 100 }, {Value: 200}, {Value: 300},];
  $scope.List_Add = [];
  $scope.click_Add = function(data) {
    if ($scope.List_Add.indexOf(data) == -1) {
      $scope.List_Add.push({ ...data});
    }
  }

  $scope.click_Update = function(data, newValue) {
    data.Value = newValue;
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.9/angular.min.js"></script>

<body ng-app="RodoApp" ng-controller="RodoController">
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in data_List">
      <td ng-click="click_Add(data)">{{ data.Value }}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <hr/>
  <table class="table table-hover table-striped">
    <tr ng-repeat="data in List_Add">
      <td>
        <a href="#" ng-show="!show_Update" ng-click="model_Value = data.Value; show_Update = true">{{ data.Value }}</a>
        <div ng-show="show_Update">
          <input type="text" ng-model="model_Value">
          <input type="button" value="Save" ng-click="click_Update(data, model_Value); show_Update = false;">
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>
```

Also, note that `indexOf` will not work anymore because of the cloning. You can add an `id` property to each object to uniquely identify an object. Then, use [`some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to check if it is already added to `List_Add`

```
if (!$scope.List_Add.some(o => o.id === data.id)) { }
```